# Can't run this simple .exe file with this Windows Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm a complete newbie to coding, so I don't understand most of the similar posts on this forum.

I'm doing a simple C programming course, and I need to run a notepad++ file from the Powershell. The file only contains this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

 int main()
  {
    int num = 931;

    printf("The number 'num' is %d\n", num);
    return 0; 
}
```

I called the file: Variables.c then I put this into the Powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\Raven\Desktop\C Programming> gcc Variables.c -o Variables.exe
```

Followed by:

```
PS C:\Users\Raven\Desktop\C Programming> Variables.exe
```

I then get the following error:

```
Variables.exe : The term 'Variables.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, funct ion, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was i ncluded, verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
+ Variables.exe
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Variables.exe:String) [], CommandNotFound     Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What is going on here??

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check the output of `gcc` to be sure that it actually compiled the code? Does executing `dir` in the powershell prompt to list the contents of the directory include a file called Variables.exe?

Comment: Hey Tom, not sure how to check the output of gcc..? But yes the dir command lists the Variables.exe file

Comment: By 'output' I mean the diagnostic information printed to the console. I don't recall exactly what the default is, but it should print *something* to tell you whether it succeeded or failed. If you see nothing at all, that's a problem.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To run an exe in PowerShell you need to either provide the full path to the exe or the relative path by preceding the filename with `.\`   Ensure you are in the correct directory and try:

```
 .\Variables.exe
```

Comment: D'oh! Yes, of course. This is one of Powershell's most common and irritating quirks.

Comment: Woww thanks a lot, it worked!! You've made my day :)

Answer (score 1):

The case is you are using windows powershell. You can execute that fileName.exe command in windows cmd (in the exe file stored path).